# Removing element from dom on click

Tags: jquery

I have an element appended to body tag on click. Currently I set it up to be removed when that element is clicked. I'd like to change the code to remove it when anything in the document is clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', 'body', function() {
    if ($('#myEm').length > 0) {
        $('#myEm').remove();
    }
});
```

However, when I test I always get a count of 1, because the element is actually added to body before my script is running. So, what happens, my element is never shown because I close it right away.

How do I get around it? Do I add some sort of delay?

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zmugx5cq/1/)

---

UPDATE: [working code](http://jsfiddle.net/zmugx5cq/11/)

Comment: You want the first body click to append the element and the second body click to remove it?

Comment: Yes, I have a link to add the element. But once it's open, I want any click top close it.

Comment: You don't show us where you add the element, but basically one of two things is happening: 1) your event is not firing (improbable, since you're assigning it to `body`, but a syntax or other error would prevent it), or 2) at the time the event fires, there is no element in the DOM with ID "myEm". You can verify this with `alert($('#myEl').length)`

Comment: Post a complete code example please so that we can see/reproduce the issue. Also, a stack snippet or jsFiddle example would be useful.

Comment: I really don't get what you are doing or what you are trying to do but this works http://jsfiddle.net/fr2qkcLr/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The click event on your span is bubbling up the DOM to the body element, and triggering the click event on it, and removing the element you just added.

Use [`stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) to prevent that bubbling:

```
$('.clickMe').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('body').append('<div id="myEm">dynamic element</div>');
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zmugx5cq/4/)**

Note also that your overall logic seems a little flawed as your code allows for multiple divs to be added to the body that have the same ID, which is verboten.

Comment: You forgot to save when updating the fiddle.

Comment: Oh, I simplified my example. In real code only a single element is added, since I remove any element with the same ID before I add it.

Comment: @j08691 Your example removes #myEm only when I click it. How do I remove it when I click anywhere?.. http://jsfiddle.net/zmugx5cq/7/

Comment: Seems to work whenever I click in the body. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tLphzhra/

Comment: Spineless coward downvoter care to grow a pair and explain the issue?